# Node module that detect updates on webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am looking for a node module that can detect changes/updates of a webpage.

For example, I want to create a watch on https://www.google.com

any updates on that page will trigger an event.

Did some search but can't find one.

Better to have a module that don't depend on any database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a web scraper to detect changes on a website. I recommend [scrape-it](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/scrape-it) as a module to do this.